# ¿Como obtener todas la filas de mysqli_fetch_array de una consulta?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

**Tengo el siguiente código, con el que solo logro obtener la primera fila, el propósito es obtener cada fila y mostrarla en un solo cuadro**

```
<?php
 include("conexion.php");  




$sql="SELECT * FROM libros  ";
$res=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);


$fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field_direct ($res,1);




$arreglo = array();


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

$arreglo[] = $row;

shuffle($arreglo);
}

foreach ($arreglo as $rows){


    <?php
         include("conexion.php");  

        $sql="SELECT * FROM catalogos  ";
        $res=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);


        $dato1= $row[1];

        $dato2=$rows[2];

        $dato3=$rows[3];

        $dato4=$rows[4];

            }



   ?>
```

**Y este codigo debe de llenar las tablas**

```
    <p>
    <table width="657" height="71" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><? echo"$dato1";?>
    <p><? echo "$dato2";?></p>
    <p><? echo "$dato3";?></p>
    <p><? echo "$dato4";?></p>
    <p><? echo "$dato5";?></td>
    <td><? ?></td>
    <td><? ?></td>
    <td><? ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>

    <table width="657" height="71" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><? ?></td>
        <td><? ?></td>
        <td><? ?></td>
        <td><? ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="657" height="71" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><? ?></td>
        <td><? ?></td>
        <td><? ?></td>
        <td><? ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

la salida debe ser algo como esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu código tratas de _reinventar la rueda_ pues ya MySQLi te devuelve el resultado en un arreglo asociativo, no tienes por qué tratar de meter en un arreglo los resultados. Puedes hacerlo con: `$row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` o bien con: `$row = $res->fetch_assoc();` así tendrás en la variable `$row` tus resultados en forma de arreglo, para mostrarlos como quieras, mediante un bucle, mediante print_r o como quieras. Te recomiendo que revises el Manual: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php  y también: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

A continuacion asumo que tu código PHP esta en el mismo donde armas el HTML (table):

```
<html>
<!-- Tus metas y referencias a link JS. CSS.... -->
<body>
<?php
   // Proceso para obtener los datos que ya tienes (primer fragmento de código que muestras
   // Desde luego esto puede ir antes del body e incluso html
   foreach($arreglo as $row){
?>
<!-- ya que al parecer quieres un table por cada fila -->
<table width="657" height="71" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td><?= $row[1]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[2]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[3]; ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[4]; ?></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<?php
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hola, a lo mejor no me explique bien pero solamente necesitaría una fila o toda la información de un solo libro en un solo cuadro pero solo logro conseguir la primera fila, no se como obtener las demás filas

Answer (score 0):

Tenia un problema parecido y me sirvio usar la funcion mysqli_fetch_all() que devuelve todas las filas, si existe mas de una en tu consulta.

fetch_all : devuelve un array por cada fila de la consulta.

es decir tendras un array principal y dentro de el uno o mas array segun el numero de filas en tu consulta.